# How to Create Network Connection between two existing VM in Azure Portal

Tags: azure, networking, virtual-machine

I have Two Azure VMs which has been created for about 6 months now. The VMs are in use by different members of the same project teams, now I want to know how I can network the VMs together (for direct transfer of large files) without having to delete and recreate them.

Answer (score 0):

@faruq bello If the VMs are in the same Virtual Network you should be able connect them without any additional configuration, if not please check the NSG rules or firewall on the VMs to see if it is blocking any connectivity.
If they are not in the same virtual network I think you can establish connectivity by using [Virtual network peering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-peering-overview) in this scenario. If the VMs are in the same Azure region you can use Virtual network peering and across Azure region  you can use Global virtual network peering. Please be aware of constraints for [globally peered virtual networks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-peering-overview#constraints-for-peered-virtual-networks).